# Wordpress - Contact form 7 email not received

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am unable to receive email in my configured email in contact form 7 (in word press). All of the email finally end up in my default email account with the subject "Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender"

The body of the email is given as under. One thing i noticed is that the 'recepient' is test@test.com, while i configured the To to my own email id. The snapshot of my config is (I changed my own domain name with sample mydomain for security purposes):

[image: Configuration]

The failure email i end up getting in the default email id is:

```
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

  test@test.com
    host secureserver.net [85.45.125.0]
    SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:<test@test.com>:
    550 5.1.1 <test@test.com> recipient rejected. This is a default recipient used as a placeholder in many web applications. Please check your settings and try again.

------ This is a copy of the message, including all the headers. ------

Return-path: <myname@secureserver.net>
Received: from myname by secureserver.net with local (Exim 4.85)
    (envelope-from <myname@secureserver.net>)
    id 1Z9pj0-002GGR-NL
    for test@test.com; Tue, 30 Jun 2015 00:12:58 -0700
To: test@test.com
Subject: [mydomain!  Contact] From hi
X-PHP-Script: www.mydomain.com/index.php for 85.52.214.184
Date: Tue, 30 Jun 2015 07:12:58 +0000
From: hi <test@test.com>
Message-ID: <b325164dd89b7dbe9861fdf0e1f578c1@##str_replacement_1##>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.7 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/)
Reply-To: hi@gmail.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Name: hi 

Email: hi@gmail.com 

Comments: hi hihihi
```

Comment: sometimes it happens when we try to send an email from same domain in the from email.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP mail function doesn't complete sending of e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-function-doesnt-complete-sending-of-e-mail)

Answer (score 0):

Sending and receving emails with CF7 works very well for most people. Anyone who has problems should check server configurations and take a look at [Contact Form 7 Email Issues](http://contactform7.com/setting-up-mail/#Contact_Form_7_Email_Issues).